# ASP.NET GridView DataKeys error - Argument out of range index out of range

Tags: asp.net

[Here is the image of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSqo0.png) Im a beginner here at asp.net, I was hoping to ask if you guys know how to solve my problem. I have a delete button which deletes checked checkboxes in my datagridview. Everytime I run the code it give me the argument out of range error (index out of range) in the `int id = Convert.ToInt32(brandgrid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]);` code?

```
            foreach (GridViewRow row in brandgrid.Rows)   
            {

                int id = Convert.ToInt32(brandgrid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]);

                CheckBox chkdel = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkDel");   
                if(chkdel.Checked)   
                     { 
                        //int id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);   
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandText = "usp_Brand_Delete";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", current);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                        cmd.Connection = sqlCon;

                        sqlCon.Open();  
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlCon.Close();
                     }
            } 

        }
```

Comment: Can you post your `GridView` in the aspx page?

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="brandgrid" runat="server" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="mGrid" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" 
 AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>

<PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
</asp:GridView>

Comment: Has your gridView filled first? Have you checked if by chance there aren't an columns in it. Did you debug it? What are the row and column count before this piece of code executes ?

Comment: @Jetlag You can check my answer below and fix accordingly.

Comment: my gridview already has data in it from the sql server database. How can you check the count though?

Comment: @Aruna Ill try your solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, From your `GridView` below, it's confirmed that you haven't set the `DataKeyNames` property in the GridView and so, its' throwing the error as you said above.

```
<asp:GridView ID="brandgrid" runat="server" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="mGrid" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"> 
   <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle> 
   <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr">
   </PagerStyle> 
</asp:GridView>
```

> From MSDN,
>
> When the DataKeyNames property is set, the GridView control
>   automatically creates a DataKey object for each row in the control.
>   The DataKey object contains the values of the field or fields
>   specified in the DataKeyNames property. The DataKey objects are then
>   added to the control's DataKeys collection. Use the DataKeys property
>   to retrieve the DataKey object for a specific data row in the GridView
>   control.

To access this property, you have to set `DataKeyNames="<ID column name>"` in your GridView.

I have added `DataKeyNames="id"` property below in your GridView assuming the column name is `ID` and but you have to check and change this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="brandgrid" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="mGrid" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"> 
   <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle> 
   <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr">
   </PagerStyle> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Also change your code as below,

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in brandgrid.Rows)   
{
     if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
          var dataKey = brandgrid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
          if(dataKey != null)
          {
                int id = (int)dataKey;

                CheckBox chkdel = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkDel");   
                if(chkdel.Checked)   
                     { 
                        //int id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);   
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandText = "usp_Brand_Delete";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", current);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                        cmd.Connection = sqlCon;

                        sqlCon.Open();  
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlCon.Close();
                     }
           }

      }
  }
```

Comment: I forgot to edit, I don't have my datasource, I manually connected it through the code

Comment: DataSource is fine, if you handled it in the code. Add `DataKeyNames` as I told

Comment: Im getting this: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'id'.

Comment: Do you have a column name called 'Id' in the data source. Please check this and provide the correct column name. It should be your primary key column in the database. If your data source is not included this column name then add the same in the respective stored proc/query.

Comment: I do have a column named id and it is the primary key also in the stored proc

Comment: Does the result set of your data source has this column? Can you add the column to the grid view and check you can see the data? For this checking you can remove the DataKeyNames property. Also, attach the UI screenshot for this column

Comment: Can you paste the grid view code and the data source code?

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="brandgrid" runat="server" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="mGrid"
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" 
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" OnRowDeleting="delete">
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
<PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
        </asp:GridView>

for my datasource code I only have my connection string and stored proc
as posted above :<

Comment: Where is the DataKeyNames ?

Comment: I removed the property to view the table and because it gives me the DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'id'.  exception

Comment: Add it back and post it here. I just want to check how it looks

Comment: Also post the code where you found the data source and the select query which you have in your db

Comment: I added the DatakeyNames="id" back but I cant view my table because it throws the exception :(

Comment: That's fine, can you post the code where you binding the grid ?

Comment: That's fine, can you post the code where you bind the grid ? And also the select query that used (inside the stored proc) to retrieve data

Comment: protected void bindgrid()
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "b_GetBrands";
            cmd.Connection = sqlCon;

Comment: sqlCon.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                brandgrid.DataSource = ds;
                brandgrid.DataBind();
        }

Comment: Also, post me the query inside the stored proc `b_GetBrands`

Comment: I managed to read the datakeys through your solution and by adding a <asp:BoundField DataField="id" Visible="false"/> but the same error shows "argument out of range" and I think it is the index[row.RowIndex] causing it, im looking for a way to get the right index of the row then change the index

Comment: Have you added the data keys back ?

Comment: yes I did :) thank you for your suggestion! I still have to find a way to get the row index

Comment: Okay, I almost found the issue what it is. Let me update the code shortly.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the code! I run it but I get InvalidCastException "Specified cast is not valid" on the int id = (int)dataKey;

Comment: I checked the values of my rows, its all 0; I think this is what causes the exception? :)

Comment: Yeah, why its all "0". Its not returning from the database. And also, check the data type whether its `string 0`?

Comment: Change the line to `int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataKey);`

Comment: It gave me "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: you have to debug why the value is not proper `integer`?

Comment: != null turned to be true so it has value in it, ill try to check

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
GridView.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) % GridView.PageSize].Value.ToString();
```